# grep linux command exclude if file name contains integer

Tags: regex, grep

Print only those files whose file name does not have any integer.

example:

```
httpdocs/bak_2016-01-10-embed.php:function displayVideo
httpdocs/bak_EMBED_embed.php:function displayVideo_flv($path,$au
```

Only show 2 file.

I am trying the below command but it is not working.

```
egrep -r --exclude='[^0-9]+\.*' "n displayVideo"
```

Comment: Please try: grep -v -E "[0-9]+"

Comment: @BalazsVago please mention full command.

Comment: Ok, should be something like:
find [directory] -maxdepth 1 -type f | grep -v -E "[0-9]+"
Where [directory] is the place where you searching, "maxdepth 1" is to scan only that specific folder (no subfolders), "-type f" is to search only files. For grep, the "-v" is to inverse search, and "-E" is for regular expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your exclude pattern is wrong.

As per man page,

> --exclude=GLOB
>
> Skip files whose base name matches GLOB (using wildcard matching).  A file-name glob can use *, ?, and [...]  as wildcards,
>   and \ to quote a wildcard or backslash character literally.

- `+` is not a valid glob character.
- To negate a class in glob we use `[!...]` where is `[^..]` is a regex syntax.
- [More about globbing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming))

---

Instead you can write

```
$ egrep -r --exclude=*[0-9]* "n displayVideo"
```

- `*[0-9]*` This pattern matches all those file names which contains at least 1 digit in it.

Comment: But why below pattern is not working when + means 1 or more repetitions.
--exclude=*[0-9]+*

Comment: @amitsingh I have added an explanation on why it didn't work before. hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks  nu11p01n73R